# Length of a composition series

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm kind of stuck in this problem on my Algebra study.

I have to prove that given $(L,\leq)$ a modular lattice, $a,b,c \in L$  such that $a \leq b \leq c$, the interval $[a,c]$ admits a composition series if and only if the intervals $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$ admit a composition series respectively and also that $l[a,c]=l[a,b]+l[b,c]$.

Of course I've proven the part of composition series, but I'm kind of confused with that " $l$ ". I think it means $length$, but I can't find any information about it.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what a modular reticle is, and a Google search has not been particularly illuminating. Do you mind providing a definition, or at least a reference to a definition?

Comment: modular reticle is a reticle in wich 2nd isomorphism theorem holds.

Comment: Aha! I do believe you mean [modular *lattice*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), sorry it was reticle that was giving me trouble actually. In that case, I would agree that length is the most likely interpretation of $l$ there.

Comment: Oh, well.  Thank you !!